# Codename One - Build Canceled By User on BLE example

Tags: codenameone

I need to develop an application for IOS and Android able to communicate with a trivial Bluetooth Low Energy device. I started looking for cross-platform solutions, and being a Java developer and open-source supporter, I Codename One to be a promising solution. I started having a look on its structure, and it seems to support BLE as well.
The problem is that when I try to compile the Bluetooth Low Energy example application provided by the guys at Codename One (https://github.com/chen-fishbein/bluetoothle-codenameone), it compiles fine, it runs on the emulator, but when sent to the CN1 build-server (I tested an Android build), I cannot retrieve the code for the app, because it shows a red label "Build Canceled By User".
I tried with the Hello World app and that works fine.
I tried with both Netbeans and IntelliJ.....
Apparently, others were able to compile the application with no problems....

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks to all!

Comment: What kind of subscription do you have? Could it be possible that the build size is over your subscription limit?

Comment: It's the free version for now, I am still evaluating if it is the right platform....but the example is really simple, I would be surprised this is the problem....Anyhow, I will check. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Free usage has some build limitations. I will suggest you take the 2 weeks free trial of the Pro account. You will have access to all Pro subscription benefits. No build size limitation, priority build and much more.

Comment: I tried once again with IntelliJ creating a new project, and this time the build worked fine and the application ran fine on my android device....maybe a bug on my netbeans, I will check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project has a broken `build.xml`. Make sure you have the latest version of the plugin. Right click the project and select `Codename One -> Codename One Settings`.

Press the save button and you should be prompted to update the `build.xml` say yes and it should fix that issue.